# gitlab-ci pass dynamic variable to environment.url

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to be able to set dynamic environment url in gitlab yml.

```
...
environment:
    url: $ENVIRONMENT_URL/?env=${echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG | grep -o '[^@]*$'}
...
```

I know that I can't use bash command in url, it should be string or variable. Is there a way to somehow set `echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG | grep -o '[^@]*$'` as variable, ie in script and use it here? Variables declared in script are local but maybe there is a way to export it to outer scope and use it in environment.url.

I've tried

```
  script:
    - VERSION_SHORT=`echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG | grep -o '[^@]*$'`
  environment:
    url: $ENVIRONMENT_URL/?env=${echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG | grep -o '[^@]*$'}
  variables:
    VERSION_SHORT: $VERSION_SHORT
```

Comment: did my answer workout for you?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set a dynamic environment url in Gitlab(depending on version of Gitlab you are using)

Make use of

```
artifacts:reports:dotenv
```

**Introduced in GitLab 12.9**

The dotenv report collects a set of environment variables as artifacts.

Gitlab parses the deploy.env report artifact, registers a list of variables as runtime-created, expands the environment:url: $DYNAMIC_ENVIRONMENT_URL and sets it to the environment URL.

```
  script:
    - VERSION_SHORT=`echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG | grep -o '[^@]*$'`                         
    - echo "DYNAMIC_ENVIRONMENT_URL=$ENVIRONMENT_URL/?env=$VERSION_SHORT" >> deploy.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: deploy.env                                                       
  environment:
    name: XYZ
    url: $DYNAMIC_ENVIRONMENT_URL
```

Comment: Awesome! I can imagine this breaking down the line, but it definitely works right now :+1: